# How to prove that $\frac{x^2+y^2}{4}\leq e^{x+y-2}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I need to prove that given any $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, such that $x,y\geq 0$, then is true that

$$\frac{x^2+y^2}{4}\leq e^{x+y-2}$$

My try was use logarithms and state that without losing generality, if $y\leq x$, I can say that

$$\ln(x^2+y^2)-2\ln(2)\leq \ln(2x^2)-2\ln(2)=2\ln(x)-\ln(2)$$

But I don't see any way to advance more and obtain that this last identity is less or equal to $x+y-2$. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: You're missing a 2 factor just after the equality; it is $2\log x$ instead of $\log x$.

Comment: @Clayton The last inequality follows from $\log x\leq x$ and the assumption that $y\leq x$.

Comment: I'm trying to obtain it. Sorry for the misunderstanding, I corrected the question to state correctly where I advanced.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois: I agree with everything you have now. Thank you for the clarification that you hadn't proved the (previous) last inequality.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Is all I have, and the fact that I can consider that the $y$ doesn't affect in anything because I could consider it like $y=0$ and the inequality should stay true.

Comment: @Clayton My apologies it does not follow, at least not inmediately, I read it too fast

Comment: @MonsieurGalois: Jonh's proof is not correct; he must multiply by $e^2$ to get the equivalent statement $$e^{x+y}\geq\frac{x^2+y^2}{4}\cdot e^2.$$

Comment: Now I see it. Thanks, I didn't see the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already solved it!! You've shown that $\log([x^2+y^2]/4)\leq x+y-2$. You just have to take exponentials on both sides and (because the exponential is an increasing map) you're done.

[It might be noteworthy that your demostration is for the case that $x$ and $y$ are not simultaneously zero, but that case is trivially true]

Edit: Not an answer, yet. I understood @MonsieurGalois had already proved that.

Reedit: It is enough to show that
$$e^{x+y}\geq\frac{x^2+y^2}{4e^2}.$$
As every term in (the power series representation of the exponential map)
$$e^{x+y}=1+(x+y)+\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}+\cdots$$
is positive it follows that $e^{x+y}\geq\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}$, and so that
$$e^{x+y}\geq\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}\geq\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\geq\frac{x^2+y^2}{4e^2}.$$

Re-reedit: As pointed out by @Clayton, another stupid flaw on me. My apologies.

Because $e^2(x^2+y^2)/4\leq e^2(x+y)^2/4$ it is enough to show that
$$e^2(x+y)^2/4\leq e^{x+y}.$$
This enables us to reduce the question to if $e^2r^2/4\leq e^r$ for $r>0$ (for $r=0$ it is trivially true). Define in that range the function
$$f(r)=4e^r/(er)^2.$$
Our problem is to prove that $f(r)\geq 1$. This value is reached at $r=2$. Furthermore, $f(r)\to+\infty$ when $r\to0$ or $r\to+\infty$. Now we are done cause taking derivatives we get that
$$f'(r)=0\Longleftrightarrow e^rr^2=e^r2r,$$
so $r=2$ is the only critical point of $f(r)$ and given the smothness of $f$ (where it is defined) along with its limits on 0 and $+\infty$ this implies that $r=2$ is the global minimun of $f(r)$.

Comment: But my way to solve it was try to create a concatenation of if-and-only-if statements considering valid de inequality trying to obtain an inequality that could be hold by trivial reasons. In my try I'm considering what I'm going to prove to obtain something true, so I don't understand why you say that I have finished already :(

Comment: @MonsieurGalois Sorry, it is not. I understood that you've already proved that.

Comment: No, I wanted to prove, but sorry too, it was wrongly written.

Comment: @MonsieurGalois Havent been able to prove it without using power series. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Well, it's a proof! :)

Comment: What you have written is (mostly) true, but it isn't what is asked. You need to *multiply* the right-hand side by $e^2$, not divide.

Comment: @Clayton Once again you right. Sorry, ots too late in my country. I am fixing it...

Comment: @Jonh: No problem. I used a similar approach and can prove it for $x+y\geq2$ (I think; I've only brushed over the details). I haven't been able to get the desired result, though.

Comment: @Clayton Finally got it. Editing...

Comment: @Clayton Done! Thank u for pointing out the previous flaws :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Jonh: +$1$ Very good!